# Why use Glassfish instead of Apache? What's it strengths and weaknesses?

Tags: glassfish

Sorry for my ignorance here, but when I hear the word webserver, I immediately imagine Apache, although I know people use Microsoft's IIS too. However since I've been hanging out here at Stackoverflow I've noticed lots of people use Glassfish.

Which made me wonder, why would I want to use Glassfish (in the sense that I'm interested, but I don't really understand why it might make my life easier). From what I read it's Sun's  open-source derivate of Apache's Tomcat, thus I imagine it's a good (or great) quality product. But since I don't know its strengths and weaknesses, I don't know when it would be wise to choose Glassfish over another server. Could anyone elaborate ?

Comment: Do you need a Web Server or a Servlet Container?

Comment: I'm thinking about WebServer primarily.

Comment: Similar Question: [*Java EE Web Profile vs Java EE Full Platform*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24239978/642706)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

GlassFish is an Application Server which can also be used as a Web Server (Http Server).

A web Server means: Handling HTTP requests (usually from browsers).

A Servlet Container (e.g. Tomcat) means: It can handle servlets & JSP.

An Application Server (e.g. GlassFish) means: It can manage Java EE applications (usually both servlet/JSP and EJBs).

You should use GlassFish for Java EE enterprise applications.

Comment: That would mean Glassfish is what one could call a lean-mean Java Server, less general purpose than Apache, but more focused and optimized for Java Servlets?

Comment: Yep, although Glassfish also has a very good HTTP handling framework.

Comment: "lean-mean" is not exactly what describes a full Java EE server.

Comment: @ShimiBandiel: Excellent description and breakdown. Thank you. :)

Comment: I an newbee here. Cant we use apache for Java applications ?

Answer (score 6):

The need for a seperate Web server is mostly needed in a production environment. You would normally find a Application server to be suffice most of your development needs. A web server is capable of holding larger number of active sessions and connections, thus providing the necessary balance without performance costs.

Stick to a simple web server if you are only working with servlets/jsps. It is also to be noted that in a netbeans environment, glassfish has better support than other App servers.   In the context of eclipse though, WSAD and JBoss seem to the preferred options.

Answer (score 3):

Glassfish will soon release the modular kernel.

This means that the containers you need start up and shutdown as you need them.  I.e no EAR deployed, EJB container won;t start up.  This seems to have made it very good for development as it can start and stop *very* quickly.  This takes it a lot closer to development environments like Rails (where redeployment is a massive part of your development)

Answer (score 2):

I have used GlassFish server for developing Web Services.
It provides a very interactive Admin Console where admin can test the Web Services.
I really find it helpful while developing Web Services