# Can we use Apache tomcat instead of JBOSS for EJBCA?

Tags: ejbca

Actaully I am trying to use EJBCA as CA in my project wherein there is already apache tomcat deployed and I am not in favour of using any other webserver. So, Can we use Apache tomcat instead of JBOSS for EJBCA?

Comment: This link might help you to some extent.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821640/what-is-difference-between-tomcat-and-jboss-and-glassfish

Answer (score 1):

No you can not a full JEE server is needed.