# Tomcat - Mysql -Persistence... Cannot create resource

Tags: java, mysql, maven, tomcat, jpa

I have a webapp running in Glassfish + postgreSQl + JPA and I am supposed to migrate it to Tomcat + MySQL.
I have the data available in MYsql but I face issue with resource creation.

Maven Project --> META-INF --> context.xml

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
          maxActive="10" maxIdle="4" 
          name="jdbc/pool" 
          password="pwd" 
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          url="jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/db" 
          username="user"/>
```

Project -- > src/main/resouces/META-INF --> persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="testPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/Pool</jta-data-source>        
    <class> </class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pwd"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Maven Project --> WEB-INF --> web.xml

```
   <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/Pool</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

I have the mysql-connector undet tomcat/lib

When deployed , tomcat logs has

```
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor F:\Dev_Env\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\conf\Catalina\localhost\TestApp.xml
Jun 12, 2014 2:37:37 PM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
```

but resource instance is not created

```
SEVERE: Servlet /TestApp threw load() exception
    javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceEnvFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceEnvFactory.java:117)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.lookupFieldResource(DefaultInstanceManager.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.processAnnotations(DefaultInstanceManager.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:535)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1461)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:357)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat does not completely supports Java EE, it is only a Servlet container (implements the Servlet and JSP specifications) 
[What is the difference between Tomcat, JBoss and Glassfish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821640/what-is-difference-between-tomcat-and-jboss-and-glassfish))

If you application is using Java EE resources (e.g. EJB), you should not be able to run it using Tomcat.

I suggest the creation of a new application from scratch using TomCat and then check if it runs, after that you can compare the configuration files to make sure that nothing from the Glassfish configuration was left behind.

Comment: I created a application from scratch and I have two persistence unit, one RESOURCE_LOCAL and another JPA. Also I have the resource configured in application context.xml.. But even then it says cannot create resource instance. I use eclipselink jpa provider.

Answer (score 0):

For tomcat you should use  and transaction_type should be "RESOURCE_LOCAL"