# Trouble creating a Hello World Web application (installing the Geronimo Eclipse Plugin)

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, geronimo

I'm trying to create a Hello World web app by following [this instructions](http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC30/developing-a-hello-world-web-application.html).

I have the java SDK and the Eclipse for Java EE; now I'm trying to install Geronimo Eclipse Plugin on Eclipse Java EE 4.5 (64 bits), following [this](http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC30/installing-geronimo-eclipse-plugin.html) instructions.

And I see the message (via 'new server'):

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>
> Software being installed: Geronimo v2.1 Server Adapter 2.1.8 (org.apache.geronimo.v21.feature.feature.group 2.1.8)
>
> Missing requirement: Geronimo v2.1 Server Adapter 2.1.8 (org.apache.geronimo.v21.feature.feature.group 2.1.8) requires 'org.apache.geronimo.st.core [2.1.8]' but it could not be found

...and via the 'install new software':

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>
> Software being installed: Geronimo v3.0 Server Adapter 3.0.1 (org.apache.geronimo.v30.feature.feature.group 3.0.1)
>
> Missing requirement: Geronimo Server Tools V30 UI Plug-in 3.0.1 (org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.ui 3.0.1) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.tm.terminal.view [2.1.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
>
> Cannot satisfy dependency:
>
> From: Geronimo v3.0 Server Adapter 3.0.1 (org.apache.geronimo.v30.feature.feature.group 3.0.1)
>
> To: org.apache.geronimo.st.v30.ui [3.0.1]

I found [this forum thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014818714), that solves by, first, enabling update site http://download.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/updates/3.2. I'm not sure how to 'enable' it, I did try add in the 'install new software' sites, but it was not found. Neither http://download.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/updates/4.5 (as my Eclipse version is 4.5).

Can anybody help me to install this Geronimo Eclipse Plugin? Or is there a better way to create a hello world web app?

**--update**

I just try with Eclipse Java EE 3.4.1 (as the instructions are for eclipse 3.4), 32 bits this time, and got the same problems.

**--update**

Via the updatesite.zip; the link on the instructions is broken, I found it [here](http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC30/developing-a-hello-world-web-application.html). But the Eclipse's installation is frozen for half an hour now. I'll try Glassfish as suggested by @paulsm4.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is less "Hello world" than "installing Geronimo".  Unless you have a compelling reason, I would suggest using a different server - *any* server - besides Geronimo.  For example: [Tomcat](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWTP/article.html), [Glassfish](https://glassfish.java.net/getstarted.html) or [Liberty](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/running-the-java-ee-7-samples-on-was-liberty/)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a solution with Geronimo, I'm moving to [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821640/what-is-difference-between-tomcat-and-jboss-and-glassfish).

Answer (score 0):

For those who still have issues - take a look at this bug report for Geronimo Dev Tools - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GERONIMODEVTOOLS-813

Answer (score 0):

For eclipse juno : Goto install new softwares and select **"updates - http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates"** in drop down and check in *project provided components* in the searched results then click on next/finish to install that plugin .Once completed restart eclipse.Now you will able to see server options in add new server wizard.