# Which is Best web server for JAVA applications in terms of resources and features?

Tags: java

I am going to select a web server for java based web application which requires access to all features of Java Enterprise Edition and have no issue in terms of resources required for my application.
Which is BEST WEB SERVER to choose in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend Apache Tomcat ,

tomcat has been the best server for J2EE applications , very stable , very secure ( when configured well ) and easy to scale.

Answer (score 0):

The answer at [What is the difference between Tomcat, JBoss and Glassfish?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3821659/9192223)

would give you a better insight to what might suit you best for your application. Adding to this, I personally feel that Apache Tomcat does a great job with very less efforts and is lightweight at the same time.